# How to get correctly content and avoid breaking html tags using strip_tags with substr?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, dom

In my page I have some post previews from RSS feeds. Every post preview shows about 300 characters. When a user clicks on expanding button, then the `#post-preview` is replaced with the `#post`. The #post shows the rest of the post.

Everything fine with this but the format of the `#post` is not good, not readable. So I thought of allowing `<br><b><p>` tags, it will make it ok to be read. Because I don't want the user to be distracted, I want the tags to be allowed after the 300 chars.

With the following method, it is possible to break some tags where the `$start` ends and `$rest` starts. This means no good readable output.

```
$start = strip_tags(substr($entry->description, 0, 300));
$rest = strip_tags(substr($entry->description, 300), '<b><p><br>');
$start . $rest;
```

My question is how can I keep `$start` and `$rest` the same (no tags) until the 300 char, and after that `$rest` will show the formatted post? Are there any other ways of doing this?

Here is an example of a RSS feed structure (from view page source).

```
<item><guid isPermaLink="false"></guid><pubDate></pubDate><atom:updated></atom:updated><category domain=""></category><title></title><description></description><link></link><author></author></item>
```

I am looking for a way that does not kill performance.

Comment: Maybe you can iterate through all characters and count the chars < and >. If there are more < than >, you simply add more characters until the needed count of > is reached to $start.

Comment: You could simply strip out all tags and show the first 300 raw text characters as the excerpt. After all, it is entirely possible that a post might have nothing BUT html tags for the first 300 chars, rendering the excerpt useless.

Comment: @MarcB Can you show me a sample please? I didn't get exactly the point...

Comment: `$start = substr(strip_tags($entry->description), 0, 300)`. Don't try to figure out how to keep html tags in there, because it's a losing game. Bypass the problem by eliminating the tags for excerpts, and leave the full document intact for the "readmore" links. Hide the tag-less excerpt when the readmore link is clicked, and just display the original full document.

Comment: @MarcB but isnt this what I posted?

Comment: No. note that the strip-tags is being done FIRST, **then** the substr.

Comment: @MarcB I tried it but again, the $rest is different from $start. I did this `$start = substr(strip_tags($entry->description), 0, 300); $rest = substr(strip_tags($entry->description, '<p><br>'), 0, 9000);`

Comment: So you want to have $start with no tags(and length of 300 chars) and the $description with tags only after 300 char? Isn't it better to have $start stripped and whole $description with tags? Maybe you should look for another solution for the whole case? If not, we'll think...:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$start = substr($entry->description, 0, 300);
if(($pos = stripos($start, "<")) !== false) {
    $start = strip_tags(substr($start, 0, $pos));
    $rest = substr($entry->description, $pos);
}
else {
    $start = strip_tags($start);
    $rest = substr($entry->description, 300);
}
```

Ok, it's just a concept. Gets first 300 chars and checks for broken tag. If broken cut before it and get $rest from this point. If not broken just strip and get rest. There is at least 1 problem:

- you never now the length of the $start(after strip_tags could be nothing left), could use loop with length checking but eeee... efficiency

**EDIT**
Ok, get it:

```
$start = "";
$chars = 400;
while(strlen($start) < 300) { 
    $start = strip_tags(substr($rss, 0, $chars));
    $chars += 50;
}
$pos = stripos($rss, substr($start, strlen($start) - 50));
$rest = substr($rss, $pos+50);
```

Ok, little nasty and there are some cases on which it fails(with repetable text probably:D), tested on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/GbzA3)

Comment: Because $rest is rest, to echo whole just echo $start.$rest;

Comment: I can echo the whole article just by $rest. The $start echoes nothing.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem I mentioned... Can you give some example data?

Comment: I am on mobile device now, but my content is Rss feed, you can view page source of any rss, looking for description tag...z