# How to use substr but keep <br> in textarea

Tags: php, html

So I've created a post function, but when I want to display the post on the front page, it should only show the first 200 letters as well as keeping all breaks the user made in the textarea. 
What I am doing is the following:

```
substr($row["content"], 0, 200);
```

and this displays the content just fine, but it lets out all breaks that the user makes.

Comment: Do you mean new lines aren't there or `<br>` was removed from the content?.. or were/are there `<br>` after the first 200 characters you want?

Comment: @Danuel Alsaker can you give the contents of $row["content"] or at least an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `newline` to `break` function to your substring:

```
nl2br(substr($row["content"], 0, 200));
```

Or if you want to save whole words:

```
nl2br(mb_substr($row["content],0,200)); //this will not strip the word in the middle, so if it longer than 200 with the last word, it ends up before that word
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Was exactly thinking about if there was a way to combine nl2br with substr as I've used them seperated from each other, was just not sure of how to combine them. Thank you C:

Answer (score 0):

take a look here

[How to get correctly content and avoid breaking html tags using strip_tags with substr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518985/how-to-get-correctly-content-and-avoid-breaking-html-tags-using-strip-tags-with)

Comment: But that's why you should substring string first, and THEN to apply nl2br.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP's End Of Line**

The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for PHP is the [PHP_EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol) constant. You can use [PHP_EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol) constant to replace the newline character in a cross-platform-compatible way with the br tag.

```
$row["content"] = str_replace(PHP_EOL,'<br>',$row["content"]);
```

**Take a look at [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**

Strip_tags will remove all HTML,XML and PHP tags from a string. You can use the optional second parameter as a whitelist.

**Keeping the BR tag**

Use **strip_tags** with whitelisting **br** and substr in one line:

```
substr(strip_tags($row["content"],'<br>'), 0, 200);
```

**Final code**

Let's combine the replace and filter steps in one code block.

```
substr(strip_tags(str_replace(PHP_EOL,'<br>',$row["content"]),'<br>'), 0, 200);
```